# discord.py on_member_joined event is not firing

Tags: python, discord.py

I am very new to python, and I am trying to create a discord bot.

Here's a member added event:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  print("a member joined")
  print(member.name)
```

For some reason, this isn't working! No errors, just not printing anything.

Earlier in I have this code:

```
import time

intents = discord.Intents.all()
```

And everything is enabled on the application page.

Comment: You need to actually pass the intents to the client constructor, i.e `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to improve your question so other users can understand you better. The title is fine but you also have to express your problem on the body of the question. Normally you will write what are you trying to do followed by the problem encountered. Then you can show code and test (in your case prints are your tests that show that the event is not firing).